# I am using CURL function to run my URL its working in localhost the same code not working in my live server

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl function to  run my joomla url its working in localhost, but not working live server.

Iam getting error like in alert please enter valid email address.

My code is here:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$option = "com_acymailing";
$ctrl = "sub";
$task = "optin";
$hiddenlists = "5";
$useremail = "test@gmail.com";
$username = "Test";
$fields = array( 'option'=>$option, 'ctrl'=>$ctrl, 'task'=>$task, 'hiddenlists'=>$hiddenlists, 'user[email]'=>$useremail, 'user[name]'=>$username);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.test.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
echo $data;
```

Please help me how to fix the issue.
Thanks

Comment: The error comes from the `echo $data`? ..your code is correct and it should work.. Also, do you have curl enabled in your live server?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make an email signup form that sends the data with cURL.
Knowing that, if you get an error saying 'Please enter a valid email address', it seems your cURL requests do work and the message is the response you get from the server you are posting to.

Use the function phpinfo() to see if cURL is enabled on the server, just to be sure.
Then check if you are sending the right POST fields.

What you can do is find a regular signup form for the application you are trying to connect with, then check all it's form fields, see if you have exactly the same fields with exactly the same names in your POST values.

Hope it helped.